# SQL Joins based on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to combine two tables and obtain total# of the name by count() and group by functions.

Table_1 is shown below as;

```
name       branch       sports             player no
----       -----        ------             --------
Mike        120         basketball           15
David       110         soccer               18
```

Table_2 is shown below as;

```
jersey color      player no        height
----------        ---------        ------
Blue               15                182
Green              18                174
```

I tried to combine two tables by inner joins and count them based on the name such as;

```
SELECT name, branch, sports,
FROM TABLE_1

INNER JOIN TABLE_2 
ON  
TABLE_1.player no = TABLE_2.player no

COUNT(name) AS TOTAL
GROUP BY name, branch, sports, jersey color, player no, height
```

output should be

```
name       branch       player no      jersey color     height      
----       ------       -------         --------         ----
Mike         120          15             Blue             182
David        110          18             Green            174
Mike         120          15             Blue             182
Mike         120          15             Blue             182
David        110          18             Green            174
```

After count(name)

```
name       branch       player no      jersey color     height      Total   
----       ------       -------         --------         ----       -----
Mike         120          15             Blue             182         3
David        110          18             Green            174         2
```

I have been pondering why I can not make this works?

Comment: Based on the data that you provided what is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: results are supposed to be combined all the column on table_1 and table_2 and counting number of name as total by grouping all the columns

Comment: Please add the table of expected results to your question. It is still not clear what you are asking for

Comment: I'm wondering why `Mike` has 3 shirts in your expected results, while `David` only has 2. Their records look identical to me.

Comment: @Chelsea please mark the answer as answer if it answers your question or explain why it doesn't if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially trying to combine the results one after the other, not side by side. This calls for a `union [all]`, not a `join`:

```
SELECT   name, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT name FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT name FROM table2) t
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: how can I combine rest of the columns into the one table?

Comment: I don't think that they need to UNION. They need to join